# Post title spoiler how?

Tags: posts, title

I want when i click post title then a hidden content will show.

The code: https://pastebin.com/W6Q22gVL

What i want to show when post title is clicked: https://pastebin.com/juy3ekXK

Comment: Please [edit] your question, and put the code into the question body.

Comment: The code gets very wierd: How to put the code correctly?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/formatting